# How to increase the lifespan of an Arduino.

Tags: arduino, lifetime

I have made a device with arduino MEGA *with 50+ one wire  sensors, 4-6 shift registers, SIM800l module, ethernet module, wifi module, RTC, SD card module, OLED, buttons, thermal printer, LM2596 buck converter etc..* All modules are soldered on my new board powered with external power supply through LM2596. My board with modules fits to arduino like a shield with male header pins.

I want to make this device to work for years continuously  (if possible) how can I **increase the lifespan**?

> Arduino Mega
>
> Description:
>
> The Mega 2560 is an update for the Arduino Mega, which it replaces.
>   The board is a microcontroller board based on the ATmega2560-16AU . It
>   has 54 digital input/output pins (of which 14 can be used as PWM
>   outputs), 16 analog inputs, 4 UARTs (hardware serial ports), a 16 MHz
>   crystal oscillator, a USB connection, a power jack, an ICSP header, 
>   and a reset button. It contains everything needed to support the
>   microcontroller;  simply connect it to a computer with a USB cable or
>   power it with a AC-to-DC adapter or battery to get started. The Mega
>   is compatible with most shields designed for the Arduino Duemilanove
>   or Diecimila.
>
> Product Summary:
>
> CH340G replace the Atmega 8U2/16U2 CH340G Driver Download link, please
>   copy the link and paste in browser: http://www.5v.ru/ch340g.htm
>   Microcontroller:ATmega2560 Clock Speed:16 MHz EEPROM:4 KB SRAM:8 KB
>   Flash Memory:256 KB of which 8 KB used by bootloader Operating
>   Voltage:5V Input Voltage (recommended):7-12V Analog Input Pins:16
>   Digital I/O Pins:54 (of which 14 provide PWM output) DC Current for
>   3.3V Pin:50 mA DC Current per I/O Pin:40 mA
>
> Package Included: 1 x ATmega2560-16AU CH340G Board

Comment: related: [Highly accelerated life test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_accelerated_life_test).

Comment: Did you know about this http://www.rugged-circuits.com/ruggeduino/ ? It gives some info on how to ruggedize an Arduino project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. All you can do is prevent damage from the elements or self induced damage from heat. Don't overdrive the regulator. Maybe add a fan if needed. Ensure water tight if you can for out door projects.

The parts have a finite life based on their component quality. As you are likely buying cheap Chinese products, expect to get what you pay for. Any bargain bin capacitors are the most likely to go first. RTC crystal next, and probably the thermal printer after that. The SD Card based on how often you write to it.

Expect, in best conditions, five years.

Comment: It is prototyping, I can replace all cheap products.. what do you suggest? The device was not hot after 1-2 days of usage, can temperature increase after stand by temperature, if yes, is a fun enough?

Comment: If none of the parts are too hot to keep your finger on it, you'll be fine. Maybe add a fan for extra protection.

Comment: Can capacitors from buck converter, modules, arduino last so many years?

Comment: Maybe. Cheap, unbranded, and possibly fake electrolytic caps can fail at any time.